# Regression on matrices

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, matrix

Given an equation in the form of

$R(\lambda) = \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{4} R_i(\lambda)^\frac{1}{n} \right )^n$

where $R$ is a $m$ by one matrix and a number of data matrices for $R$, can nonlinear least square regression be performed to find the optimal value for $n$ when the parameters are matrices? How is regression done on matrix parameters?

Background: $R(\lambda)$ is actually the function of light reflectance at frequency $\lambda$, so $R$ and $R_i$ are functions. $R_i(\lambda)$ is the reflectance of the $i^{th}$ colour at $\lambda$. I've collected reflectance values over a spectrum range and I'm trying to find the (optimal) value for $n$.